# Error:No such file or directory when tried to access nginx.conf using path /opt/nginx/conf/

Tags: nginx

When i tried to configure the webserver through the path cd /opt/nginx/conf/ an error appears /opt/nginx/conf.Hope some one will have the answer here.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably your config is under `/etc/nginx`, to check which directories nginx is using you can use the command `whereis nginx`